# perl File::Tail syncronization

Tags: perl, synchronization, daemon, tail

im having this situation:
Im parsing some log files with perl daemon. This daemon writes data to mysql db.

Log file can:

1. be rotated ('solved by filesize and some logic')
2. doesnt exist ('ignore_nonexistant' parameter in Tail)

Daemon:

1. Can be killed
2. Can became dead by some reazon.

Im using File::Tail to tail tha file. For file rotation mechanism of date of creation or filesize can help. and what mechanism should i use to start tail from some position in file? (asume that there is a lot of such daemons, no write access to filesystem).

I've think about position variable in DB, but this wont help me.

Maybe some mechanism to pass position parameter to parrent process?

I just dont want to reinvent bicycle.

Answer (score 2):

File::Tail already detects rotation and continues reading from the new file.

To deal with the daemon dying and restarting, can you query the database for the last record written when the daemon restarts, and just skip logfile lines until you get to a later line?

Answer (score 2):

Try http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Unrotate/.
You'll have to implement your own `Log::Unrotate::Cursor` class if you wish to store position files in DB instead of local filesystem, but that should be trivial.

We wrote and used `Log::Unrotate` for 5 years in production and it tries really hard to never skip any data. (It tries so hard that it throws exception if your cursor becomes invalid, for example if log got rotated several times while reader didn't work for some reason. You may want to enable `autofix_cursor` option to change this behavior).

Also take a look at http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-LogReader/. I never used it but it's supposed to solve the same task.

Comment: imagine that there is a list of files to be parsed. you run yours main(parent) daemon that generates childrens for each file. now this works like this: remembers last line that was parsed and monitors file size and file length (num of lines). if something go wrong it finds that line in file.log file1.log file.1.tar.gz and like file*bydate.log -> and starts from last position. this line is stored in mysql db. but thats is every line update command